# Valores de un array string no pasan de un form a otro

Tags: c#, formularios, windows

He estado intentando pasar los valores de un array string a otro array string en un segundo form. Lo que pasa es, que a la hora de correr el programa, el valor del string no aparece en el segundo form, solo aparece... nada y ya no se que mas tratar.

Adicionalmente, hay un array de objetos (CJugador Jugador) que no puedo utilizar en el segundo form debido a su nivel de acceso. Pero al intentar ponerlo publico, dice que sobrepasa el nivel de acceso de form 2. No entiendo de verdad que es lo que esta pasando. Ya intentamos de todo con mi pareja y es imposible hacer que los labels en el form 3 tengan el texto del array string en el form 2

```
namespace Gambit
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        //Atributos (Se crea el array para los nombres)
        public string[] listaJugadores = new string[6];

        Label[] listaLabels = new Label[6];

        CJugador[] jugador = new CJugador[4];

        public string[] listaFinalJugadores = new string[6];

        public int contador = 0;

        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            listaLabels[0] = this.label1;
            listaLabels[1] = this.label2;
            listaLabels[2] = this.label3;
            listaLabels[3] = this.label4;
            listaLabels[4] = this.label5;
            listaLabels[5] = this.label6;
        }

        //Se activa el boton para mostrar los nombres registrados
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            //Esto hara que se agureguen los nombres a la lista de jugadores

            jugador[contador] = new CJugador();
            jugador[contador].nombre = txtNombres.Text;

            listaJugadores[contador]= txtNombres.Text;

            listaLabels[contador].Text= txtNombres.Text;

            if (contador <= 4)
            {
                contador++;
            }
            else
            {
                contador = 0;
            }

            Random rnd = new Random();
            int value = rnd.Next(0, 10);


            textBox1.Text = value.ToString();

        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (contador == 4)
            {

                //Esto va a crear un orden aleatorio en el array que se creo con anterioridad
                Random rnd = new Random();
                string[] jugadoresRandom4 = listaJugadores.OrderBy(x => rnd.Next()).ToArray();

                jugadoresRandom4.CopyTo(listaFinalJugadores, 0);


                //Abriremos el forms que nos servira para jugar con 4 personas
                Form3 TableroPara2 = new Form3();
                this.Hide();
                TableroPara2.Show();
            }

            else if (contador == 5)
            {
                //Esto va a crear un orden aleatorio en el array que se creo con anterioridad
                Random rnd = new Random();
                string[] jugadoresRandom6 = listaJugadores.OrderBy(x => rnd.Next()).ToArray();


                //Abriremos el forms que nos servira para jugar con 6 personas
                Form4 TableroPara6 = new Form4();
                this.Visible = false;
                TableroPara6.Show();
            }
            else
            {
                label1.Text = " ";
                label2.Text = " ";
                label3.Text = " ";
                label4.Text = " ";
                label5.Text = " ";
                label6.Text = " ";

                string mensaje = "Tienes que ingresar 4 o 6 jugadores. Intentalo de nuevo.";
                MessageBox.Show(mensaje);

                contador=0;
            }

        }
    }
}



            //Creamos un array de objetos que tendran nuestras propiedades
            CJugador[] jugador = new CJugador[4];

            //Creamos  un ciclo for para crear jugadores en su respectivo array con los atributos "nombre" ranzomizados.
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                jugador[i] = new CJugador();
                jugador[i].nombre = arrayJugadores[i];
            }

            label1.Text = FormRegistro.listaFinalJugadores[0];
            label2.Text = jugador[1].nombre;
            label3.Text = jugador[2].nombre;
            label4.Text = jugador[3].nombre;
        }
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            Form2 FormRegistro = new Form2();


            Random rnd = new Random();
            int value = rnd.Next(0, 10);

            if (Enumerable.Range(0,15).Contains(value))
            {

            }


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: En Form3 debes tener un constructor parametrizado, donde el parámetro será de tipo Label[]. De ese modo, con la ayuda del constructor de la clase Form3, podrás tener la referencia de ese objeto y asignar los textos en donde tu quieras.

Comment: @MrDave1999 disculpa, podrias ayudarme un poco mas? Recien estoy empezando a entender tu respuesta pero no entendi muy bien. Muchas gracias de antemano! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > Ya intentamos de todo con mi pareja y es imposible hacer que los labels en el form 3 tengan el texto del array string en el form 2

Para lograrlo, el constructor del `Form3` debe estar parametrizado, es decir, necesita tener un parámetro de tipo `Label[]` donde recibirá la referencia del objeto.

Imagínate que nuestro `Form2` está construido de esta forma:

```
class Form2 : Form
{
    Label[] listaLabels = new Label[6];
    public Form2()
    {
    }
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Pasamos la referencia que tenga guardada listaLabels al parámetro del constructor.
        Form3 form3 = new Form3(listaLabels);
    }
}
```

Luego, nuestro `Form3` debería estar estructurado de este modo:

```
class Form3 : Form
{
    Label[] listaLabels;
    public Form3(Label[] p_listaLabels)
    {
        //Le pasamos la referencia que tenga guardada p_listaLabels a listaLabels
        listaLabels = p_listaLabels;
    }
}
```

Hay otra forma de hacerlo, pero deberás declarar el atributo `listaLabels` como estático en `Form2` y para poderlo usar en el otro formulario, deberás crear un
`getter` para tener acceso al atributo.

Por ejemplo:

```
class Form2 : Form
{
    private static Label[] listaLabels = new Label[6];

    public static Label[] ListaLabels
    {
        get
        {
            return listaLabels;
        }
    }

    public Form2()
    {
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form3 form3 = new Form3();
    }
}
```

Ahora, la forma de usar el `getter` (es un método que nos sirve para tener acceso a un atributo privado de una clase) en el `Form3` sería de esta manera:

```
class Form3 : Form
{
    public Form3()
    {
        //Dará como resultado el primer label que tenga guardado el arreglo de objeto
        MessageBox.Show(Form2.ListaLabels[0].Text);
    }
}
```

De esta forma no necesitaríamos crear un constructor parametrizado.

Comment: Intente el metodo de getter. Lastimosamente, cuando salio solo "Label1". Lo raro es que a la hora de pasar un valor del textbox en el form 2 a una label ahi mismo, si aparece, pero luego ya no :/

Comment: @Juan No entiendo cual es el problema. Deberías de actualizar tu pregunta y mostrar en donde está el posible error.

Comment: @Juan lo que te pasa es que al abrir tu form lo ves, y despues al cambiar algo ya no ves ese cambio en el otro form?